# Why is a process suspended by another process behind it?

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, cocoa, process

The code is in a simple way, only read and parse an xml file into an array. I did not notice the problem until one day I tried to open a **big** xml file.

I added a blur view with NSProgressIndicator when the data is parsing, but the blur view did not show up until the parsing was completed.

```
self.addBlurView()
let file = HandleFile.shared.openFile(filePath)
self.removeBlurView()
guard let name = file.name, let path = file.path, let data = file.data else {
    return
}
```

So I tried to delay parsing data. The blur view can be showed up, and removed when completed.

```
self.addBlurView()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3, execute: {
    let file = HandleFile.shared.openFile(filePath)
    self.removeBlurView()
    guard let name = file.name, let path = file.path, let data = file.data else {
        return
    }
})
```

I thought it might be a problem fo thread, so I tried this in `func addBlurView()`, **failed**. I also tried to add an counting in `addBlurView()`, it counted to a certain number and paused, and continue counting after parsing data.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.blurView.isHidden = false
    self.spinner.startAnimation(self)
}
```

Have no idea why this happen. Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Try wrapping `let file = HandleFile.shared.openFile(filePath)` in `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async` main Queue is a serial queue and all the tasks assigned to it are executed serially by main thread. In general, You should not perform any heavy lifting task (like loading file to memory) on main thread as it would block the main thread and render UI unresponsive. Its hard to answer without actually seeing the implementation of `openFile(` but normally such tasks should have completion block to tell you that file is loaded and in that block you can switch to main queue and remove blurV

Comment: Yes, put all things in `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async`, and update UI in main queue, it works fine. Thx. Would you mind post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: seems like you upvoted the answer but havent accepted it, to accept the answer please click on the tick mark below up and down arrow :)

Comment: Sorry for delay, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, main queue is a serial queue and all the tasks assigned to it are executed serially by main thread. In general, You should not perform any heavy lifting task (like loading file to memory) on main thread as it would block the main thread and render UI unresponsive.

Typically all the heavy lifting tasks like loading a file to a memory (anything which does not deal with UI rendering directly) should be delegated to one of dispatch queues. Try wrapping your `openFile(filePath)` call inside `DispatchQueue`

```
        self.addBlurView()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            let file = HandleFile.shared.openFile(filePath)
        }
```

Personally I would expect `openFile` function to have a completion block which is triggered on main queue when it finished loading file so that you can remove your blurView, but in your case it seems like its a synchronous statement so you can try

```
        self.addBlurView()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            let file = HandleFile.shared.openFile(filePath)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.removeBlurView()
            }
        }
```